# Master page showing digits instead of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

[image]I am using visual studio 2012. I was working on asp.net master page . suddenly my system hang  and i restarted. when i open my vs my master page is showing digits on the whole page and there  is no code  at all . I have restarted vs many times but the problem remains. please help i have no back up and it was very important code.

Comment: Your file has become corrupted, basically erased and filled with 0 bytes. Get the previous version from version control or backup. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure it's lost forever.

Comment: how to get previous version

Comment: If you don't know about version control or backup, then you don't have them, and your file is lost. Maybe you can try to get previous versions in Windows Explorer (right click, properties), but that's it.

Comment: if you are some kind of lucky you can find on your "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder that is on the "windows / microsoft.net / framework" the compiled versions of your files. There you may get some code back. Also you may run a program that's try to restore some of your corrupted data. And then you may setup a backup program for the next time.

Comment: program is not running giving errors.